# What's the fastest way to increase color image contrast with OpenCV in python (cv2)?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, contrast

I'm using OpenCV to process some images, and one of the first steps I need to perform is increasing the image contrast on a color image.  The fastest method I've found so far uses this code (where np is the numpy import) to multiply and add as suggested in the [original C-based cv1 docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html):

```
    if (self.array_alpha is None):
        self.array_alpha = np.array([1.25])
        self.array_beta = np.array([-100.0])

    # add a beta value to every pixel 
    cv2.add(new_img, self.array_beta, new_img)                    

    # multiply every pixel value by alpha
    cv2.multiply(new_img, self.array_alpha, new_img)
```

Is there a faster way to do this in Python?  I've tried using numpy's scalar multiply instead, but the performance is actually worse.  I also tried using `cv2.convertScaleAbs`  (the OpenCV docs suggested using `convertTo`, but cv2 seems to lack an interface to this function) but again the performance was worse in testing.

Comment: It would be already faster. It is just a addition and multiplication.

Comment: The addition and multiplication operations can be done simultaneously to get interesting effects. Basically, every pixel can be transformed as `X = aY + b` where `a` and `b` are scalars. This is a linear transform. I have shown quadratic transform in the answers which produces much more interesting outcomes ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simple arithmetic in numpy arrays is the fastest, as Abid Rahaman K commented.

Use this image for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9ZxT.png

Here is a bit of image processing that resembles brightness/contrast manipulation:

```
'''
Simple and fast image transforms to mimic:
 - brightness
 - contrast
 - erosion 
 - dilation
'''

import cv2
from pylab import array, plot, show, axis, arange, figure, uint8 

# Image data
image = cv2.imread('imgur.png',0) # load as 1-channel 8bit grayscale
cv2.imshow('image',image)
maxIntensity = 255.0 # depends on dtype of image data
x = arange(maxIntensity) 

# Parameters for manipulating image data
phi = 1
theta = 1

# Increase intensity such that
# dark pixels become much brighter, 
# bright pixels become slightly bright
newImage0 = (maxIntensity/phi)*(image/(maxIntensity/theta))**0.5
newImage0 = array(newImage0,dtype=uint8)

cv2.imshow('newImage0',newImage0)
cv2.imwrite('newImage0.jpg',newImage0)

y = (maxIntensity/phi)*(x/(maxIntensity/theta))**0.5

# Decrease intensity such that
# dark pixels become much darker, 
# bright pixels become slightly dark 
newImage1 = (maxIntensity/phi)*(image/(maxIntensity/theta))**2
newImage1 = array(newImage1,dtype=uint8)

cv2.imshow('newImage1',newImage1)

z = (maxIntensity/phi)*(x/(maxIntensity/theta))**2

# Plot the figures
figure()
plot(x,y,'r-') # Increased brightness
plot(x,x,'k:') # Original image
plot(x,z, 'b-') # Decreased brightness
#axis('off')
axis('tight')
show()

# Close figure window and click on other window 
# Then press any keyboard key to close all windows
closeWindow = -1
while closeWindow<0:
    closeWindow = cv2.waitKey(1) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original image in grayscale:

[image]

Brightened image that appears to be dilated:

[image]

Darkened image that appears to be eroded, sharpened, with better contrast:

[image]

How the pixel intensities are being transformed:

[image]

If you play with the values of `phi` and `theta` you can get really interesting outcomes. You can also implement this trick for multichannel image data.

**--- EDIT ---**

have a look at the concepts of 'levels' and 'curves' on [this youtube video](http://youtu.be/hZeMqXxMG_8) showing image editing in photoshop. The equation for linear transform creates the same amount i.e. 'level' of change on every pixel. If you write an equation which can discriminate between types of pixel (e.g. those which are already of a certain value) then you can change the pixels based on the 'curve' described by that equation.

Comment: What if I need to compile both features, increasing the Brightness of dark pixels and decreasing the brightness of Over bright pixels at the same time. Can we achieve this behaviour.

Comment: I tried but didn't get the desired results, any suggestions

Comment: @Anmol_uppal as i said in the --- EDIT --- portion, you will have to find that equation which does so. the simplest method i can think is to use cv2.inrange() function for modifying the pixels within a lower and upper bound. you may merely need to call cv2.inrange() twice for two different bounding conditions.

Comment: @samkahn13 it would be of much help if you could guide  me something in context of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370075/descent-image-equalization

Comment: @samkhan13 what would be the best way to darken the dark pixels and brighten the lighter ones. I see no example in your answer

Answer (score 21):

Try this code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sunset.jpg', 1)
cv2.imshow("Original image",img)

# CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3., tileGridSize=(8,8))

lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # convert from BGR to LAB color space
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  # split on 3 different channels

l2 = clahe.apply(l)  # apply CLAHE to the L-channel

lab = cv2.merge((l2,a,b))  # merge channels
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # convert from LAB to BGR
cv2.imshow('Increased contrast', img2)
#cv2.imwrite('sunset_modified.jpg', img2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Sunset before:
[image]
Sunset after increased contrast:
[image]

Comment: The OP asks for the ***fastest*** contrast enhancement, for them a linear transform is not fast enough! how does your proposed solution compare — speedwise — with the not-fast-enough procedure in the OP?

Comment: @gboffi -- Yes, "the fastest way"... I was so thoughtful about making sharper color image, that the essence of the question didn't come to my mind :-). As I know NumPy has a speed of C language, because it is written in C. Is it faster way than C? Yes, it is Assembler :-). I don't think that there is faster algorithm than linear transformation of 2D matrix. So if OP make linear transformation of 2D matrix on Assembler it will be faster than C language (or NumPy which is written in C). I don't think that CLAHE is faster than NumPy linear transformation, because it is more complex algorithm.

Comment: This code has the disadvantage that it increases the contrast of the Luminance channel but leaves the color channels unchanged. So the result image has reduced color contrast. Your pictures are not the best example. When you try this with other photos that have more colors and less contrast you will notice that this code does not produce the optimal results.

Comment: I forgot the question, but answer is wonderful. I am thankful you to contribution to my knowledge of color science.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cv2::addWeighted](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19) function. It will be faster than any of the other methods presented thus far. It's designed to work on two images:

> dst   =   cv.addWeighted( src1, alpha, src2, beta, gamma[, dst[, dtype]]  )

But if you use the same image twice AND you set beta to zero, you can get the effect you want

> dst   =   cv.addWeighted( src1, alpha, src1, 0, gamma)

The big advantage to using this function is that you will not have to worry about what happens when values go below 0 or above 255. In numpy, you have to figure out how to do all of the clipping yourself. Using the OpenCV function, it does all of the clipping for you and it's fast.