# How increase the contrast of an image with opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to increase the `contrast` of the bellow picture, with `opencv c++`.

[image]

I use `histogram` processing techniques e.g., **histogram equalization** (HE), **histogram specification**, etc. But I don't reaches to good result such as bellow images:

[image]

What ideas on how to `solve` this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the `internet` can I find help?

Answer (score 4):

I found a useful subject on `OpenCV` for changing image contrast :

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

double alpha; /**< Simple contrast control */
int beta;  /**< Simple brightness control */

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 /// Read image given by user
 Mat image = imread( argv[1] );
 Mat new_image = Mat::zeros( image.size(), image.type() );

 /// Initialize values
 std::cout<<" Basic Linear Transforms "<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"-------------------------"<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"* Enter the alpha value [1.0-3.0]: ";std::cin>>alpha;
 std::cout<<"* Enter the beta value [0-100]: "; std::cin>>beta;

 /// Do the operation new_image(i,j) = alpha*image(i,j) + beta
 for( int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++ )
    { for( int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++ )
         { for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
              {
      new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =
         saturate_cast<uchar>( alpha*( image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] ) + beta );
             }
    }
    }

 /// Create Windows
 namedWindow("Original Image", 1);
 namedWindow("New Image", 1);

 /// Show stuff
 imshow("Original Image", image);
 imshow("New Image", new_image);

 /// Wait until user press some key
 waitKey();
 return 0;
}
```

See: [Changing the contrast and brightness of an image!](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html)

Comment: this a linear transformation and it doesn't reaches to good result such as images in top.

Comment: @AlirezaAlipourBloordokani have any method else linear transformation? can this help you?  See:[the fastest way to increase color image contrast...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363293/whats-the-fastest-way-to-increase-color-image-contrast-with-opencv-in-python-c)

Comment: I use all techniques but they don't reach to good result such as images in top. I need a powerful algorithm .....

Comment: @AlirezaAlipourBloordokani i can offer you, to reading an Image Processing book. because it analysis all methods such as : Artificial Intelligence. perhaps this can help you.

Comment: I read "OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook" and "Learning OpenCV ", but  they can not help me.

Comment: @ Mohammadreza Panahi I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363293/whats-the-fastest-way-to-increase-color-image-contrast-with-opencv-in-python-c but I can't convert to c++. Could you help me convert it to c++?

Comment: @AlirezaAlipourBloordokani if you haven't any solution, you must use of a common method, that every body use of it. i hope you to be succeed!

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but you could try to reduce the number of colours by merging grays into darker grays, and light grays into whites.

E.g.:

- Find the least common colour in <0.0, 0.5) range, merge it towards black.
- Find the least common colour in <0.5, 1.0> range, merge it towards white.

This would reduce the number of colours and help create a gap between brigher darker colours *maybe*.

Comment: This could be better achieved by using a cluster algorithm such as k-means.
Here is a tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/07/color-quantization-opencv-using-k-means-clustering/

Answer (score 2):

This might be late, but you can try createCLAHE() function in openCV. Works fine for me.