# How do I increase the contrast of an image in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to Python OpenCV. I have read some documents and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363293/whats-the-fastest-way-to-increase-color-image-contrast-with-opencv-in-python-c) but I am unable to figure out what the following code means:

```
if (self.array_alpha is None):
    self.array_alpha = np.array([1.25])
    self.array_beta = np.array([-100.0])

# add a beta value to every pixel 
cv2.add(new_img, self.array_beta, new_img)                    

# multiply every pixel value by alpha
cv2.multiply(new_img, self.array_alpha, new_img)
```

I have come to know that `Basically, every pixel can be transformed as X = aY + b where a and b are scalars.`. Basically, I have understood this. However, I did not understand the code and how to increase contrast with this.

Till now, I have managed to simply read the image using `img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)`

Thanks for your help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905481/python-opencv-cv2-easy-way-to-increase-the-brightness-and-contrast-of-an-image/58142491#58142491

Answer (score 87):

I would like to suggest a method using the [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space).

LAB color space expresses color variations across three channels. One channel for brightness and two channels for color:

- L-channel: representing lightness in the image
- a-channel: representing change in color between red and green
- b-channel: representing change in color between yellow and blue

In the following I perform adaptive histogram equalization on the L-channel and convert the resulting image back to BGR color space. This enhances the brightness while also limiting contrast sensitivity. I have done the following using OpenCV 3.0.0 and python:

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('flower.jpg', 1)
# converting to LAB color space
lab= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l_channel, a, b = cv2.split(lab)

# Applying CLAHE to L-channel
# feel free to try different values for the limit and grid size:
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
cl = clahe.apply(l_channel)

# merge the CLAHE enhanced L-channel with the a and b channel
limg = cv2.merge((cl,a,b))

# Converting image from LAB Color model to BGR color spcae
enhanced_img = cv2.cvtColor(limg, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

# Stacking the original image with the enhanced image
result = np.hstack((img, enhanced_img))
cv2.imshow('Result', result)
```

**Result:**

The enhanced image is on the right

[image]

You can run the code as it is.
To know what CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization) is about, [refer this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization#:%7E:text=Contrast%20Limited%20AHE%20(CLAHE)%20is,slope%20of%20the%20transformation%20function.)

Comment: In addition to Wikipedia, the Python tutorials for OpenCV have a [nice section on CLAHE](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)

Comment: Can you add the code for defining a and b in `cv2.merge((cl,a,b))` please?

Comment: @WolfgangSpindeler I have added the line `l_channel, a, b = cv2.split(lab)`

Answer (score 74):

For Python, I haven't found an OpenCV function that provides contrast. As others have suggested, there are some techniques to automatically increase contrast using a very simple  formula.

In the [official OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html), it is suggested that this equation can be used to apply both contrast and brightness at the same time:

> new_img = alpha*old_img + beta

where alpha corresponds to a contrast and beta is brightness. Different cases

```
alpha 1  beta 0      --> no change  
0 < alpha < 1        --> lower contrast  
alpha > 1            --> higher contrast  
-127 < beta < +127   --> good range for brightness values
```

In C/C++, you can implement this equation using cv::Mat::convertTo, but we don't have access to that part of the library from Python. To do it in Python, I would recommend using the [cv::addWeighted](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html) function, because it is quick and it automatically forces the output to be in the range 0 to 255 (e.g. for a 24 bit color image, 8 bits per channel). You could also use `convertScaleAbs` as suggested by @nathancy.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('input.png')
# call addWeighted function. use beta = 0 to effectively only operate one one image
out = cv2.addWeighted( img, contrast, img, 0, brightness)
output = cv2.addWeighted
```

The above formula and code is quick to write and will make changes to brightness and contrast. But they yield results that are significantly different than photo editing programs. The rest of this answer will yield a result that will reproduce the behavior in the GIMP and also LibreOffice brightness and contrast. It's more lines of code, but it gives a nice result.

### Contrast

In [the GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), contrast levels go from -127 to +127. I adapted the formulas [from here](https://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/image-processing-algorithms-part-5-contrast-adjustment/) to fit in that range.

> f = 131*(contrast + 127)/(127*(131-contrast))
> new_image = f*(old_image - 127) + 127 = f*(old_image) + 127*(1-f)

To figure out brightness, I figured out the relationship between brightness and levels and used information in [this levels post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510072/algorithm-for-adjustment-of-image-levels/48859502#48859502) to arrive at a solution.

```
#pseudo code
if brightness > 0
    shadow = brightness
    highlight = 255
else:
    shadow = 0
    highlight = 255 + brightness
new_img = ((highlight - shadow)/255)*old_img + shadow
```

### brightness and contrast in Python and OpenCV

Putting it all together and adding using the reference "mandrill" image from [USC SIPI](http://sipi.usc.edu/database/):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open a typical 24 bit color image. For this kind of image there are
# 8 bits (0 to 255) per color channel
img = cv2.imread('mandrill.png')  # mandrill reference image from USC SIPI

s = 128
img = cv2.resize(img, (s,s), 0, 0, cv2.INTER_AREA)

def apply_brightness_contrast(input_img, brightness = 0, contrast = 0):
    
    if brightness != 0:
        if brightness > 0:
            shadow = brightness
            highlight = 255
        else:
            shadow = 0
            highlight = 255 + brightness
        alpha_b = (highlight - shadow)/255
        gamma_b = shadow
        
        buf = cv2.addWeighted(input_img, alpha_b, input_img, 0, gamma_b)
    else:
        buf = input_img.copy()
    
    if contrast != 0:
        f = 131*(contrast + 127)/(127*(131-contrast))
        alpha_c = f
        gamma_c = 127*(1-f)
        
        buf = cv2.addWeighted(buf, alpha_c, buf, 0, gamma_c)

    return buf


font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fcolor = (0,0,0)

blist = [0, -127, 127,   0,  0, 64] # list of brightness values
clist = [0,    0,   0, -64, 64, 64] # list of contrast values


out = np.zeros((s*2, s*3, 3), dtype = np.uint8)

for i, b in enumerate(blist):
    c = clist[i]
    print('b, c:  ', b,', ',c)
    row = s*int(i/3)
    col = s*(i%3)
    
    print('row, col:   ', row, ', ', col)
    
    out[row:row+s, col:col+s] = apply_brightness_contrast(img, b, c)
    msg = 'b %d' % b
    cv2.putText(out,msg,(col,row+s-22), font, .7, fcolor,1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    msg = 'c %d' % c
    cv2.putText(out,msg,(col,row+s-4), font, .7, fcolor,1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    
    cv2.putText(out, 'OpenCV',(260,30), font, 1.0, fcolor,2,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)
```

[image]

I manually processed the images in the GIMP and added text tags in Python/OpenCV:
[image]

**Note:** @UtkarshBhardwaj has suggested that Python 2.x users must cast the contrast correction calculation code into float for getting floating result, like so:

```
...
if contrast != 0:
        f = float(131*(contrast + 127))/(127*(131-contrast))
...
```

Comment: @Nykodym, you were completely right about your comment. The Answer has been significantly edited to be more consistent.

Comment: Awesome, much better :) Deleted the old, out-of-the-context comment and +1.

Comment: When the contrast value is -127 it is supposed to give a solid gray image. But this algorithm gives a completely transparent image. Is this what this algorithm is supposed to do or I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 71):

Contrast and brightness can be adjusted using alpha (`α`) and beta (`β`), respectively. These variables are often called the *gain* and *bias* parameters. The expression can be written as

[image]

OpenCV already implements this as [`cv2.convertScaleAbs()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscaleabs), just provide user defined `alpha` and `beta` values

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

alpha = 1.5 # Contrast control (1.0-3.0)
beta = 0 # Brightness control (0-100)

adjusted = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

cv2.imshow('original', image)
cv2.imshow('adjusted', adjusted)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Before `->` After

[image]
[image]

**Note:** For automatic brightness/contrast adjustment take a look at [automatic contrast and brightness adjustment of a color photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905592/automatic-contrast-and-brightness-adjustment-of-a-color-photo-of-a-sheet-of-pape/56909036)

Comment: When the image data isn't zero centered (and that's usually the case in OpenCV) adjusting alpha does not correspond to changing **only** the contrast. You show this quite clearly with the example. The modified image is brighter although it appears you only wanted to change the contrast. I added an answer myself that shifts the brightness according to the contrast chosen.

Comment: `convertScaleAbs` should not be used in this way, because if the resulting values are ever negative, they don't saturate at zero, instead an absolute value is applied.

Answer (score 18):

There are quite a few answers here ranging from simple to complex. I want to add another on the simpler side that seems a little more practical for actual contrast and brightness adjustments.

```
def adjust_contrast_brightness(img, contrast:float=1.0, brightness:int=0):
    """
    Adjusts contrast and brightness of an uint8 image.
    contrast:   (0.0,  inf) with 1.0 leaving the contrast as is
    brightness: [-255, 255] with 0 leaving the brightness as is
    """
    brightness += int(round(255*(1-contrast)/2))
    return cv2.addWeighted(img, contrast, img, 0, brightness)
```

We do the `a*x+b` adjustment through the `addWeighted()` function. However, to change the contrast without also modifying the brightness, the data needs to be zero centered. That's not the case with OpenCVs default uint8 datatype. So we also need to adjust the brightness according to how the distribution is shifted.

Comment: This was actually the most helpful question as the others were missing the brightness adjustment if you wanted to keep it untouched.

Answer (score 10):

Best explanation for `X = aY + b` (in fact it `f(x) = ax  + b`)) is provided at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/906280/357701

A Simpler one by just adjusting lightness/luma/brightness for contrast as is below:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
cv2.imshow('test', img)
cv2.waitKey(1000)
imghsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


imghsv[:,:,2] = [[max(pixel - 25, 0) if pixel < 190 else min(pixel + 25, 255) for pixel in row] for row in imghsv[:,:,2]]
cv2.imshow('contrast', cv2.cvtColor(imghsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR))
cv2.waitKey(1000)
raw_input()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
img = cv2.imread("/x2.jpeg")

image = cv2.resize(img, (1800, 1800))

alpha=1.5
beta=20

new_image=cv2.addWeighted(image,alpha,np.zeros(image.shape, image.dtype),0,beta)

cv2.imshow("new",new_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: There are some really good, detailed answers with a lot of upvotes on this question. It's fine to add another answer if the existing answers are missing something. But given how detailed they are, and how much they've been validated by the community, it'd be _really_ useful to update your answer to explain what you're doing, and why you see it as an improvement over those existing answers. Would you mind doing that?

Comment: @JeremyCaney I Added, because It is very straightforward and people make it complicated, Just few line of VERY SIMPLE code, and we get our expected result, if it's wrong, then I can remove it!

Answer (score 0):

Reference from [enter link description here](https://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/image-processing-algorithms-part-5-contrast-adjustment/)

We have to calculate a contrast correction factor given by the formula below.

[image]

For the algorithm to work correctly, the contrast correction factor ( F ) value must be stored as a floating-point number, not an integer. The C value in the formula indicates the desired contrast level.

[image]

the next step is to perform the actual contrast adjustment itself. The following formula shows the contrast adjustment made to the red component of a color:

The truncate function only ensures that the new values of red, green and blue are within the valid range between 0 and 255.

The contrast value will be in the range of -255 to +255. Negative values will decrease the amount of contrast, and conversely, positive values will increase the amount of contrast.

Here you set the contrast as -128 (decreased) and +128 (increased).

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

imageContrast = image.copy()
height, width, _ = image.shape

def truncate(value):
    if value < 0:
        return 0
    elif value > 255:
        return 255
    else:
        return value


def adjustContrast(pixel, contrast=0):
    b, g, r = pixel
    f = (259 * (contrast + 255)) / (255 * (259 - contrast))
    bNew = (int)(truncate(f * (b - 128) + 128))
    gNew = (int)(truncate(f * (r - 128) + 128))
    rNew = (int)(truncate(f * (r - 128) + 128))
    return bNew, gNew, rNew

clist = [-128, 128]

plt.subplot(1, len(clist) + 1, 1)
plt.title("Orjinal")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

for index, contrast in enumerate(clist):
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            _b, _g, _r = adjustContrast(image[j, i], clist[index])
            imageContrast[j, i] = [_b, _g, _r]

    plt.subplot(1, len(clist) + 1, index + 2)
    plt.title("Contrast:" + str(contrast))
    plt.imshow(imageContrast)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]