# Convert gif image loaded in Pillow to png

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, tesseract, urllib, imutils

I'm scraping a web page that is protected by showing the information as an image so as not to be scraped. when I import an image with the format `.gif` it sends an error. I have tried to find a way to convert that imported image to another format like png, but I have not been successful.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import imutils

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
url = "url.gif"

rawimge = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))

image = imutils.resize(rawimge, width=400)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
result = 255 - thresh

phone = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(phone)


cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'GifImageFile' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Any sane reason for using 3 **Image Processing Libraries** in the same code?

Comment: yes, it is recommended by @nathancy at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58105988/12155246)

Comment: Please provide a proper working example with a fully representative URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could not convert the image container to another format, so I chose to convert the image to a file and work on it.

```
img = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
img.save("image.png")
image = cv2.imread("image.png",0)
```